# Process visualization based on data

Tags: charts, filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to use a Google spreadsheet to visualize a customer journey.

I am trying to create the following graphic:

[image]

I have created the following example spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iaza4zog4PVTpzw_6eWY8rPyQifzaRKaLNyl0AbZA3o/edit?usp=sharing

Any suggestions on how to visualize the customer journey?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doable but your data needs to be reorganized a bit:

**cell B16:**

```
={"Attention";
"Information";
"Lead";
"Contact";
"Sales";
"After-Sales"}
```

**cell C16:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
 VLOOKUP(B16:B21, FILTER({E2:E13, D2:D13}, B2:B13="Persona 1"), 2, 0), 
 "Website", 1), "Mailbox", 2), "Call", 3)*1)
```

**cell D16:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
 VLOOKUP(B16:B21, FILTER({E2:E13, D2:D13}, B2:B13="Persona 2"), 2, 0), 
 "Website", 1), "Mailbox", 2), "Call", 3)*1)
```

And then your chart can be like:

[image: 0]

Comment: Thx is it also possible to display the channel instead of 1,2,3?

Comment: no that would not be possible. charts need to have some numbers/values